# order of bm and amsmath packages, why it makes difference which is loaded first?

Tags: amsmath, bm

when I put `\usepackage{bm}` after `\usepackage{amsmath}` I get errors in the following MWE. `bm` has to be before `amsmath` to remove the errors. I thought these packages can be loaded in any order.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand*{\dot}[1]{\overset{\bm .}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\boldsymbol{\dot{\omega}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Error is `pdflatex HW4.tex`

```
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
.....
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty) (./HW4.aux)
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.11 \boldsymbol{\dot{\omega}}
```

When the order is

```
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Then no error. The strange thing is that the macro

```
  \renewcommand*{\dot}[1]{\overset{\bm .}{#1}}
```

is after both packages are loaded, so why it makes a difference which one is loaded first? since by the time the macro is read, both packages are loaded? If I remove the above macro, then the order can be changed with no error. It is only when the above macro is there, that the order makes difference.

The above macro is not my code, I got it from this forum long time ago and do not remember now which post I saw it at. If I find out, will add a link.

Any idea why this is the case?

TL 2015, linux mint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `bm` should be loaded after `amsmath` (precisely, after `amsbsy`), because it redefines `\boldsymbol` to be the same as `\bm`.

What's wrong is your redefinition of `\dot`: you can't nest calls of `\bm`, that's all.

If you do `\bm{\dot{\omega}` you get a bold dot, without any need for a redefinition.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\bm{\dot{\omega}}\ne\dot\omega
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

What happens with your code, when `bm` is before `amsmath`? That the redefinition of `\boldsymbol` doesn't happen, but the output you get is bad, in my opinion: just compare.

[image]